# python dictionary value begins by 0

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not getting exact result in python with the values leading zero. Please tell me what is going on there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067409/not-getting-exact-result-in-python-with-the-values-leading-zero-please-tell-me)

I want to create dictionary which value begins by 0. However, after I create dictionary value has changing. What I do wrong?

```
>>> sample={'first_value':0123456}
>>> sample
{'first_value': 42798}
```

Comment: `>>> sample={'first_value':123456}
>>> sample
{'first_value': 123456}`. The leading zero seems to be the culprit, bit this behaviour is VERY odd!

Comment: If for some reason you can't easily get rid of the leading zero, try `int('0123456', 10)`

Comment: The duplicate question reveals that a leading zero is used for octal number notation. Interesting.

Comment: Thank you, I did not find anything about this issue (possible duplicate), I am sorry. Important is I know answer, now. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Note that this notation is specific to Python 2.x (and earlier). In Python 3.x and later, the leading zero indicates a decimal number (that is, nothing special). Octal literals are introduced with the form `0o123456` (analogous to `0x` for hex literals).

Comment: In python3 I got error :   File "<stdin>", line 1
    sample['first_value']=012345
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: @GregHewgill, I'm glad they changed it in Python 3. This "feature" was probably inherited from C, and definitely violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 7):

The leading zero is telling Python to interpret it as an octal number.

Comment: So, there is no way to store value which begins with 0?

Comment: @AliIsmayilov: not as an *integer* (because the leading zero is not significant), but certainly you can do so as a *string*. `{'first_value':'0123456'}`

Comment: What do you expect "value which begins with 0" to mean? How is `012` supposed to be different from `12`?

Comment: When you store telephone numbers you need 0 at the beginning.

Comment: Telephone numbers aren't numbers.  They are strings of digits.  Numbers denote quantity or magnitude or something "mathy".

Answer (score 2):

Numbers starting with `0` are considered [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). You'll either need to wrap the number temporarily in a string or format `123456` with a leading zero when used; both times you can't get an integer with leading zeros (just a numeric string).

Option 1:

```
>>> sample={ 'first_value' : '0123456' }
>>> sample['first_value']
'0123456'
```

Option 2:

```
>>> sample={ 'first_value' : 123456 }
>>> '{0:07}'.format(sample['first_value'])
'0123456'
```

Answer (score 1):

The leading zero makes the value an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Answer (score 0):

When you write 0123456, it gets interpreted as base-8, which is 42798 decimal